# Difference between 商店 and 店舖?

Tags: mandarin

Can someone explain the difference between 商店 and 店舖? The dictionary differences are not clear.

1) For instance, if you want to say, "My friend works at a store in the downtown area," which would you use?

2) Are there any key differences between 商店 and 店舖?

Thanks!

Comment: try bkrs for dictionary   **商店**   在室内出售商品的场所：百货商店│零售商店  用以出售商品的建筑物
节日里商店和办公室都关门 买卖货物的店铺。
如：「这里真热闹，大小商店林立。」
百货商店 department store
儿童用品商店 children's goods store
礼品商店 gift shop
批发商店 wholesale department
特产商店 speciality shop
杂货商店 dry goods store
五金商店 hardware store
夫妻老婆商店 a mom and pop store
廉价商店 ten-cent store
友谊商店 Friendship Store
昼(日)夜商店 day-and-night shop
那家商店东西很贵。 That's a dear shop.

  **店铺**  ：泛指商店 shop; store:
照管店铺 tend shop
沿街的商号店铺 stores and shops along the street

Comment: @user6065 thanks but bkrs appears to be a russian site? could you post as an answer btw? it would be easier to read what you're saying. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

商店 refers to "store" that sell goods, for example, a book store where books were sold.

店舖 refers to "commercial establishment".  A restaurant, a DVD rental store (younger generation might not had seen one ), and of course, a book store,  are all 店舖

Comment: between 商店 and 店舖, which one is more commonly used? from your example, it appears 店舖 is more general?

Comment: 商店 and 店舖 are both commonly used. If you ask "how many 商店 in this mall" you are asking "how many stores (that sell goods) in this mall" ; If you ask "how many 店舖  in this mall"  you are asking "how many commercial establishments, including stores that provide service are in this mall" If you ask "How many 單位 in this mall" you are asking " how many units are in this mall, including commercial  and non-commercial establishments like doctor office, government outlet

Comment: the difference between 商店 and 店舖 is like the different between 'hand gun' and 'firearm'- hand gun is a kind of firearm, firearm include gun and other weapons that use gun power and bullets

Comment: the additional comments are very helpful, thank you!